# Need a Tutorial or Explanation about SAP OpenUI5 user session management

Tags: sapui5

I'm new in SAP OpenUI5, I need an Explanation or tutorial that shows session management like user login and user log out in a standalone OpenUi5, but I cannot find any. If somebody knows, please share. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session handling, authorization handling, or encryption are not part of OpenUI5 and need to be handled by the server-side.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to complement OpenUI5 with a matching opensource backend for secure Odata V2, which significantly limits OpenUI5's wider usage. There is hope it will change with the OpenUI5's Odata V4 adoptions.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "there is no easy way to complement OpenUI5 with a matching opensource backend for secure Odata V2"?

Comment: There is no free out of the box server application that provides odata features to authenticated users